# C# Newtsonsoft.Json - Deserialize JSON with nested arrays to DataTable

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datatable, dataset

I have JSON data with nested arrays (see example below).  What I am trying to accomplish is to deserialize this data into a DataSet where each nested array gets inserted into a corresponding datatable.

Example:

```
[
{
    "Id": "1",
    "LastName": "John",
    "FirstName": "Doe",
    "MiddleInitial": "I",
    "DateOfBirth": "2000-10-05",
    "Gender": "M",
    "LastModifiedDate": "2017-03-13 14:36:53",
    "Classes": [
        {
            "ClassNumber": "21",
            "TeacherID": "15"
        },
        {
            "ClassNumber": "12",
            "TeacherID": "10"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Id": "2",
    "LastName": "Jane",
    "FirstName": "Doe",
    "MiddleInitial": "K",
    "DateOfBirth": "2000-10-05",
    "Gender": "F",
    "LastModifiedDate": "2017-03-13 14:36:53",
    "Classes": [
        {
            "ClassNumber": "11",
            "TeacherID": "8"
        },
        {
            "ClassNumber": "4",
            "TeacherID": "26"
        }
    ]
}]
```

So the dataset would contain 2 datatables.  One with all of the records from the main array and the second with all of the records from the "Classes" array.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of problem you have. Please provide error details or expected/actual results. And some code of course

Answer (score 0):

You kind of have to create the DataSet and its DataTables manually and fill them manually. There's no automatic way of doing it, if that's what you were hoping for. If you need to maintain the relationships between the objects you have to add a foreign key to the Class anyway, otherwise there's no way to know which person a Class belongs to.

The table columns could be generated from the JSON properties, of course, if you're careful enough with how you write the code or if the JSON structure is always the same without exception.